# react-native-keychain crashing while using getGenericPassword function

Tags: react-native, react-native-keychain

I have a react-native app, and I'm trying to recover the user credentials after the timeout (token expiration). But when I use the function "getGenericPassword()" my app doesn't get the credentials, the app continues running but I can't get the desired values. I get no error or warning from the log. There are no information.

Some additionals about the package.json:

```
"react-native": "0.61.5"
"react-native-keychain": "5.0.1"
```

Could someone help me with that?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please add a warning here? So we understand exist issue

Comment: Same issue I was faced you need reset date on logout using this method `await Keychain.resetGenericPassword();`. and again set data on login.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! I solve the problem with the accepted solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is stucked here, I solve the problem updating the version from react-native-keychain to 7.0.0 and increasing the compileSdkVersion to 28

Comment: I'm on version 8.1.1 and this is still happening occationally - kiling app and restarting is the only fix I've found (but this is obviously not a solution)